USB3.0 to M2 (SATA) for data streaming with Rasberry Pi 4CM on single PCIEx1 Gen 2?
Project Problem Statement
Greetings, my project requires a fast RF I/Q data stream of ~ 96MB/s to SSD storage. With limited space and development time, my plan is to use a Raspberry Pi 4 CM to serve this purpose. However, there is only one PCIe x2 line available on the RP4 CM.
Current Solution
My current solution is to split the PCIe line into two using a PCIe Switch (TDS4A212MX). One PCIe line will serve the USB 3.0 Host Device (TUSB7320), and the other will connect to an M.2 SSD (SATA).
My questions

Is there any fault with my approach? If so, could you suggest an alternative?
How can I properly switch between PCIe x1 lines using the PCIe switch so that no data is lost? So far, I have not encountered any documentation that addresses this.
How should I properly terminate unused USB 3.0 ports? This is not mentioned in the datasheet. I currently plan to leave them open.


To help get an answer can you [edit] the question to include a schematic of the proposed interconnections. E.g. (a) It isn't clear where the "fast RF I/Q data stream" is connected (b) The TDS4A212MX isn't a PCIe switch, but a "high-speed differential channel multiplexer(Mux)/demultiplexer(De-Mux) switch".

Have you determined if there will be sufficient bandwidth for your peripherals over a single PCIe lane?

Hi Colin, the PCIEx2 can support upto 500MB/s of data transfer which is enough for SATA II  which required 300MB/s and RF data stream which is ~96MB/s.
